# Connecting a reverse proxy to a database mapping subdomains to IPs

Tags: database, reverse-proxy

I'm thinking of a system with one unique **reverse proxy** frontend and many **VPS** backends. Each **VPS** has its own Apache and web application but they don't have an Internet connection. Internet connection is only available to the **reverse proxy** and it will dispatch requests to **VPS** s according to their subdomains (each **VPS** is mapped to a subdomain). Here comes the question part:

What **reverse proxy** to choose?

My criteria:

1. It must be able to dispatch requests according to their subdomains.
2. It should be able to connect to a database so it can retrieve the **IP** address of the **VPS** which it has to send the request to considering the subdomain of the request.

As I am new to **reverse proxy** servers I'm not sure if my expectations are out of the question or pretty ordinary that all such servers support by default. Or perhaps some **reverse proxy** comes with a programming support which I can introduce my own code to it so I can connect to database and tell it which **IP** to send the request to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question, it's called **[mod_proxy_express](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_express.html)** and it's available in Apache 2.4.